# Can't get foreign key to work in Propel2

Tags: php, mysql, orm, propel

I am trying to use Propel2 for my web-application. I just can't figure out why my foreign-key connection does not work. It is very similar to the Book-example and that works fine.

My schema.xml:

```
<database name="default" defaultIdMethod="native"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xsd.propelorm.org/1.6/database.xsd">

    <!-- Table Structure: 'Games' -->
    <table name="games" phpName="Game">
        <column name="game_id" type="INTEGER" required="true" sqlType="int(11) unsigned" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
        <column name="game_name" type="VARCHAR" size="150" required="true"/>
        <unique name="UNIQUE_game_name">
            <unique-column name="game_name" size="150" />
        </unique>
    </table>

    <!-- Table Structure: 'Teams' -->
    <table name="teams" phpName="Team">
        <column name="team_game" type="INTEGER" required="true" sqlType="int(11) unsigned"/>
        <column name="team_id" type="INTEGER" required="true" sqlType="int(11) unsigned" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
        <column name="team_name" type="VARCHAR" size="150" required="true"/>
        <index name="KEY_teams_for_constraints">
            <index-column name="team_game" size="11" />
            <index-column name="team_id" size="11" />
        </index>
        <index name="KEY_teams_name_check">
            <index-column name="team_game" size="11" />
            <index-column name="team_name" size="150" />
        </index>
        <foreign-key name="FK_team_game" foreignTable="games" phpName="Game" refPhpName="Team">
            <reference local="team_game" foreign="game_id"/>
        </foreign-key>
    </table>

</database>
```

My PHP test-code:

```
echo "----- ----- -----  PROPEL TEST (START) ----- ----- ----- <BR><BR>";

echo "--1--<BR>";
$game = new Game();
$game->setGameName('PropelTestGame10');
echo "--2--<BR>";
$team = new Team();
$team->setTeamName('Propel Test Team10');
$team->setTeamGame($game);
echo "--3--<BR>";
$team->save();
echo "--4--<BR>";
var_dump($team->toArray());
echo "<BR>";
echo "--5--<BR>";

echo "----- ----- -----  PROPEL TEST (END) ----- ----- ----- <BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>";
```

The PHP code generates this output:

```
----- ----- ----- PROPEL TEST (START) ----- ----- -----
--1--
--2--
Notice: Object of class Game could not be converted to int in E:\MyApp\Model\Base\Team.php on line 351
--3--
--4--
array(3) { ["TeamGame"]=> int(1) ["TeamId"]=> int(10) ["TeamName"]=> string(18) "Propel Test Team10" }
--5--
----- ----- ----- PROPEL TEST (END) ----- ----- -----
```

If the game-table is empty, nothing is stored in the database. In this case there is an old row with in the game-table and inserted team is associated with that game (TeamGame=1). Nothing new is saved to the game-table.

What am I doing wrong?
I can't see why my structure should not work when the book-example does ([Propel 2 - Book-example](http://sandbox.propelorm.org/example/bookstore)).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your mistake:

```
$team->setTeamGame($game);
```

You are trying to set `team_game` column to object value. You wrote in your schema that this will be integer so this auto-generated function in base class expects integer value. You should use:

```
$team->setGame($game);
```

if you want to set related object or you can use:

```
$game->save();
$team-setTeamGame($game->getPrimaryKey());
```

Here is your [working example](http://sandbox.propelorm.org/0c0cc0b)